# LaTeX Indices: 'passim'

Tags: indexing

Is it possible to add an entry to the index that is 'passim'? This is used to mean "everywhere" or "throughout". So you'd have something like:

> Frege, Gottlob, *passim*

TIA.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[I guess](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/277964), you are using MakeIndex and either package `makeidx` or `imakeidx`. In this case, you could use the *page number formatting feature* similar to adding a *see*, e.g.,

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{imakeidx}% or just makeidx but imakeidx does the makeindex run automatically
\makeindex

\newcommand*{\passim}[1]{\textit{passim}}

\begin{document}

\index{Frege, Gottlob|passim}

Just one more index entry: Franz Frege\index{Frege, Franz}

\printindex

\end{document}
```

[image: passim]

See the `makeindex` manual for more information about using `|` (resp. the configured *encap character*).

If this does not answer your question, please ask a new one with more details, i.e., a [minimal working example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/277964), that can be used to understand and reproduce your problem.

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I was looking for. It's a bit of a hack, putting the formatting commands to a probably unintended use, but it works.